# Creating background service which displays message when user starts any installed application

Tags: android

I tried to create the service in the sense when the user clicks on application, message is shown to the user containing the name of application. I didn't find any piece of code for the solution. I will be glad if you suggest a solution. Thank You.

I found some code but it didn't work properly. It is showing message for one application only i.e the application in which the service is running. I want to show messsage for all installed applications.

```
@Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {


                            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
                            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
                            String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
                            Toast.makeText(this, activityOnTop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *when the user clicks on application, message is shown to the user containing the name of application* ?? can you please elaborate ? Your title doesn't match with your descirption

Comment: when user starts any application then the message containing the name of application should be shown. Sorry for the title if it doesn't match.

Comment: You can get [APP NAME](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon) but Not sure how can you handle the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, How this service part will work?

But here is a code which helps you to know which app is in foreground.

```
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager
            .getRunningTasks(1);

    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    final PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(componentInfo.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }
    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm
            .getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
    System.out.println("applicationName = " + applicationName);
```

Unfortunately : **getRunningTasks method was deprecated in API level 21** :(

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)

So be careful using this, and wait until SO users find any other solutions.

Comment: What you are try to achieve, please be specific. We all are giving so much efforts to solve your problem.

Do you want to know which app user is currently working on OR 
all the applications running in background?

Comment: I just want to display a message when user starts application. Message can contain the package name or application name. For that I have created the background service and code for on start of service is already added by me. The code which I have added only show message for one application i.e. the application in which service is created.

Comment: Dude, that should be it, because while you are starting your service that app is only running in foreground. Put above code inside endless loop(while(true) {}) and make sure your service is running, then open another application. See if this works.

Comment: using while loop hangs the application. It stops responding

Comment: As I said, service part I don't know. But its tricky, you must have used Service, make instead IntentService and make sure it works forever.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of While loop I have used timer and this works for me

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId,int ff) {

     int delay = 100;  
     int period = 1000;  
     Timer timer = new Timer(); 
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
         { 
             public void run() 
             { 
                  demoz();  

             } 
         }, delay, period); 

     return START_STICKY;

     }

 void demoz(){

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
                String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
                Toast.makeText(CreatedWith.this, activityOnTop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```